Number of group actions
Suppose that we have an action of a group $G$ on a $\Bbb{Z}$. This action corresponds to a homomorphism $\varphi: G \to Aut(\Bbb{Z}) \simeq C_2$. But we can have many homomorphisms of $G$ on $C_2$. Is it possible to determine how many actions we have? At least if $G$ is finite? Is this bounded by the order of $|Aut(\Bbb{Z})|$?

$\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$?  It should be $S_{\mathbb{Z}}$,  the symmetry group of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $C_2$ is abelian, a homomorphism $\varphi : G \to C_2$ automatically factors through the abelianization $G/[G, G]$. This may be easy or difficult to compute depending on what you know about $G$ but e.g. it is straightforward to compute if you're given a finite presentation of $G$, since you just take the same presentation for the abelianization (and compute Smith normal form). So we can reduce to the abelian case.
So now let $A$ be an abelian group. Any homomorphism $\varphi : A \to C_2$ further automatically factors through the quotient $A/2A$, or equivalently the tensor product $A \otimes \mathbb{F}_2$, which is an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space, the largest $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space quotient of $A$. So we can further reduce to this case, and now the answer is that the set of all such homomorphisms can be identified with the $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear dual $(A \otimes \mathbb{F}_2)^{\ast}$ of this vector space.
More concretely, suppose $A$ is finitely generated, and write $A \cong \mathbb{Z}^r \oplus T_2 \oplus T_{\text{odd}}$ where $\mathbb{Z}^r$ is the free part, $T_2$ is the $2$-power torsion, and $T_{\text{odd}}$ is the odd torsion. Then
$$A/2A \cong \mathbb{F}_2^r \oplus (T_2/2T_2);$$
in other words, taking this quotient has the effect of killing the odd torsion, turning the free part $\mathbb{Z}^r$ into $\mathbb{F}_2^r$, and doing something a bit more complicated to the $2$-power torsion. More precisely, if we write $T_2 \cong \oplus_{i=1}^k C_{2^{n_i}}$ as a direct sum of $s$ cyclic groups, then $T_2/2T_2 \cong \oplus_{i=1}^s \mathbb{F}_2$; each one just gets replaced by a copy of $\mathbb{F}_2$. Altogether we get that
$$A/2A \cong \mathbb{F}_2^{r+s}$$
so the same is true of the dual and there are $2^{r+s}$ homomorphisms $A \to C_2$.
